# Can I adjust my League of Legends advanced settings without being in a game?

Tags: league-of-legends

As far as I can tell, there's no way to adjust my keybinds or options like screen resolution and the like without actually *being in a game*. The options screen that you get from opening the launcher options only allows you to adjust the volume, help tooltips, etc. I can't adjust the advanced settings without being inside of a game.

I don't want to join one and then sit there futzing with options while my team is busy. Is there some sort of hidden settings button in the launcher...somewhere... that I'm missing? Is it possible to open a sort of dummy-game without penalty just to mess with my settings? Or am I stuck trying to adjust these on the fly in AI/PvP games?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Many of the settings can be changed manually if you know what you're doing in the game files, but unfortunately a lot of these are not supported to be changed from anywhere except from within a game. In fact, some of them are not even supported in there, and MUST be changed manually!

The official wiki has a multitude of examples listed [here](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Hotkeys_and_Commands)

You can always start a Custom Game with no penalty for leaving, and without requiring other people to be in game. You may choose to add bots as well to mess around with settings that may depend on seeing enemies and teammates (such as the side indicators for teammates, and the Tab overview screen).

Note that Custom is different than Co-Op vs. AI.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize there wasn't a penalty for leaving custom games, as I'd never made one before.

Comment: @FallenAngelEyes No problem. Custom games are where most people go to play the popular "alternate" game modes like 'All Random All Mid' (ARAM) or 'Catch the Teemo'

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use [Enigma's Settings Modifier](http://enigmablade.net/lol-settings-modifier/)