# What does the option "Use Movement Prediction" do?

Tags: league-of-legends

After messing around a little looking at the advanced options in League of Legends ([now that I know how](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37000/can-i-adjust-my-league-of-legends-advanced-settings-without-being-in-a-game)), I noticed this toggleable option:

- `Use Movement Prediction`

I turned it on to see what it does, but I couldn't see any noticeable difference in the UI or clicking on the map for pathing. I couldn't find anything on the LoL Wikia wiki either. What does turning on this option do, and when would you want to use it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Movement prediction is a display option that only comes into play if you temporarily lose your connection to the game server. Without it, your champion will appear to stand still until you regain connection and receive your true position from the server. With it, your champion will appear to move to the location you last directed it to.

Comment: isn't this the same as lerp in css? meaning if predicts the movement of other players so the latency doesn't care anymore (if it is predicting good).